# Long array of small data points is rendered as a jagged line

Tags: javascript, highcharts

### The Goal

I'm attempting to render a long series of data (around 200 ticks, from small float values like 1.3223) into a line chart.

### The Issue

When I use a series of data that changes only a small amount (around 0.0001 every tick), the chart is rendered as *very jagged* (scissor like). I would like to somehow fix it to have a "saner" radius between each point on the graph.

### A Good Example

On the other hand, when rendering higher values (around 1382.21) with bigger difference between ticks (from 0.01 to 0.05 +/-) the graph is rendered more smooth and aesthetically pleasing.

***Edit***: As user [Arie Shaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/483266/arie-shaw) pointed out, the actual low or high values don't make a difference and it remains an issue of representing small "monotonous" changes is a less jagged form.

### The Code

```
var initChart = function(data, container) {
    new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            type: "area",
            renderTo: container,
            zoomType: 'x'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        color: '#A3D8FF',
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                fillColor: '#C6E5F4',
                lineWidth: 1,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                shadow: false,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                },
                threshold: null
            }
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: "TEST",
            data: data
        }]
    });
};
```

Both graphs, and sample data sets are presented in the following fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/YKbxy/2/

Comment: Can you round down your data to only 2 or 3 decimal places?

Comment: It is the data sample that makes the graph jagged. The graph is just visualization of the underlying data. What you said "Good Example" was  just a set of data that **happens** to have smooth graph representation. And here is jagged version of the "Good Example": http://jsfiddle.net/ArieShout/ZdVJW/, which has "higher values (around 1382.21) with bigger difference between ticks".

Comment: jeff - No I must use the data with full precision.
@arie-shaw - Thanks for clarifying that up, I Agree that the data is the cause of the graph being represented like that, the question remains - is there a way in highcharts/stock to smoothen out these extreme angles?

Comment: @tutuDajuju highcharts/stock doesn't support this feature. You can try to insert additional data between every two sample points according to the points' value to smoothen the underlying data sample.

Comment: You could always manually set the limits min/max for the y-axis so that the line looks straight... Not sure why you would want that though.  The data is jagged.  That is what happens when you oscillate between two numbers.

Comment: basically it's what the client wants. the graph is more intended to show the intent or general behavior of the data then be precise representation. Therefore for a minor change like that a small variation should be shown relative to major variations in the data. I thought about setting min/max values initially a bit more far but I'm not sure when the graph actually starts to become jagged. Also the data set is being added to async so the points in the future might change the min/max required ... any idea how to implement a computation like that?

Comment: areaspline??? Is not what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing is unavoidable: If you have a lot of small variations over time, the graph is going to appear jagged *provided that you show each data point*.

The key point is that last phrase.

One way to 'smooth out' the rough parts would be to average the data. For example:

```
var myData = []; //... Some array of data; assuming just numbers

var averageData = function (data, factor) {
    var i, j, results = [], sum = 0, length = data.length, avgWindow;

    if (!factor || factor <= 0) {
        factor = 1;
    }

    // Create a sliding window of averages
    for(i = 0; i < length; i+= factor) {
        // Slice from i to factor
        avgWindow = data.slice(i, i+factor);
        for (j = 0; j < avgWindow.length; j++) {
            sum += avgWindow[j];
        }
        results.push(sum / avgWindow.length)
        sum = 0;
    }
    return results;
};

var var initChart = function(data, container) {
    new Highcharts.Chart({
        series: [{
            name: "TEST",
            data: averageData(myData, 2)
        }]
    });
});
```

This method also has the advantage that you could (potentially) reuse the function to compare the averaged data to the regular data, or even toggle between how much to average the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `areaspline` instead of `area`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/YKbxy/3/

Answer (score 0):

why dont you treat you .00001 data as 1, so times 10000, and then write it in  your legend like that.

You should even do that as a test, since if the chart looks fine then, it means there is a problem in the dataset numbers when you return it to normal, since high charts takes the difference between high and low...

Answer (score 0):

Either you must approximate your data by only using a few decimal places or you must average out the values using something like:

```
var data = new Array(200);
var smallArray = new Array(5);
var averagedData = new Array(20);
for (var index=0; index<=averagedData.length; index++){
    for(var i = 0; i<=smallArray.length; i++){
        smallArray[i] = data[i + index * 5];
    }
    averagedData[index] = (smallArray[1] + smallArray[2] + smallArray[3] + smallArray[4] + smallArray[5])/smallArray.length;
}
```

Then you will only need to plot 20 averaged points on an array of 200 data points. You can change the values for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the issue is in the frequency of the points or their plotting on yAxis.

When I provide more realistic positioning (e.g timestamp) it will look good.

Meaning that jaggedness is a result of the small changes over constant yAxis progression, which is most similar to nt3rp's answer